# ! Missing { inserted. Lost on where it's missing

Tags: math-mode, subscripts, superscripts, underline

Console reads:

```
! Missing { inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \@@overline 
l.136 \(\mu_\overline{x}
                        =\mu\)
```

This is what I have:

```
$\mu_\overline{x}=\mu$  
$\sigma_\overline{x}=\sigma/\sqrt{n}$
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Did you try ``\mu_{\overline{x}}`` and ``\sigma_{\overline{x}}``?

Comment: That worked like a charm! So do I need to put \overline{} in {} whenever it is a subscript?

Comment: Yes, and also for superscripts.

Comment: I would go even further and would say that you should always brace the whole subscript: Compare `a_ij` and `a_{ij}`. The fact that you don't need to use braces for single letters (as in `a_k`) and some simple constructs is more of an artefact of how TeX works rather than a full feature you should rely on.

Comment: Thank you for your advice!